# Warning "dump_dir not found" when running grunt

Tags: meteor, gruntjs, pdfmake

*I am trying to use the grunt plugin dump_dir to generate a vfs_font.js file for pdfmake.*

I installed **grunt ~0.4.2**, configured **Gruntfile.js**, installed the **grunt_dump_dir** plugin and checked the **package.json** file.

Yet every time I try to start grunt dump-dir, I receive the following error:

```
Warning: Task "dump-dir" not found. Use --force to continue. Aborted due to warnings.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In your Gruntfile, in the json you pass to grunt.initConfig, there should be a task called "dump_dir". For example,
The task "hello" in the following Gruntfile can be run as grunt hello,

```
grunt.initConfig({
   "hello":{},
});
```